# Limit of a function with e.

Tags: limits, functions

I'm struggling with calculating the limit of the following function:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$$
I tried using L'Hopital's rule, but I'm still getting $\frac{0}{0}$ and the denominator keeps getting greater exponent.

Comment: write $$y=\frac{e^{1/x}}{x}$$ and take the logarithm

Comment: A plot suggests that the left limit is 0 and the right limit infinite. I guess l'Hospital doesn't work because those two are different.

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Just asking. How can you take logarithm? Am I right to say that $y<0$ since $x\to 0^-?$

Answer (score 4):

Change $t=-1/x$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{-1/t}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}-\frac{t}{e^t}
$$